# What do P and Q refer to in the Minkowski distance?

Tags: machine-learning, metric

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_distance) gives some explanation and a figure about the Minkowski distance:

> The [Minkowski distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_distance) is a metric in a normed vector space which
>   can be considered as a generalization of both the Euclidean distance
>   and the Manhattan distance.
>
> The Minkowski distance can also be viewed as a multiple of the power
>   mean of the component-wise differences between $P$ and $Q$.
>
> The following figure shows unit circles (the set of all points that
>   are at the unit distance from the centre) with various values of $p$:

The figures are as follows:

[image]

In this case, what do P and Q refer to?

Comment: Reading the article, it might be a typo.  I highly suspect P and Q are points in some appropriately dimensioned space, but the authors have yet to introduce them prior to this sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P$ and $Q$ should be changed to $X$ and $Y$, they refer to the two points of which we are measuring the distance.

Power mean of the difference is $$M_p(X-Y)=\left( \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-y_i)^p \right)^\frac1p=\frac{D_p(X,Y)}{n^{\frac1p}}.$$

$$D_p(X,Y) = n^\frac1{p}M_p(X-Y).$$

Here, the multiple is $n^\frac1p$.